# Is there a way to use <inheritdoc /> within a <list>?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using XML tags to document my program so I can see descriptions when I hover over my classes, methods, and such. I want to display a list on one of my classes like so:

```
/// <remarks>
/// <b>List of methods below</b>
/// <list type="table">
///     <listheader>
///         <term>
///             <see cref="MyMethod()"/>
///         </term>
///         <description>
///             <inheritdoc cref="MyMethod()"/>
///         </description>
///     </listheader>
/// </list>
/// </remarks>
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MyMethod()
    /// </summary>
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The problem is that <inheritdoc /> is not loading anything in the preview. However, When I move <inheritdoc /> outside of the <list>, with the exact same formatting, it displays perfectly. Is there any way to reference the description of MyMethod() within the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<inheritdoc>` by default includes all members in the target XML comments. If you need the `<summary>` you need to select it using the [`path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#inheritdoc) attribute:

```
<inheritdoc cref="MyMethod" path='//summary/text()'/>
```

It should render something like this:

[image]